# Cannot add a textview to a toolbar?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

This has been bothering me for few weeks.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I copied this view Controller from a sample project.

Now I need to replace the `Textfield` with a `UITextView` instead.

The problem is I can't seem to be able to drag and drop it to a `Bar Button Item`.

I literally removed the `textField` then tried to drag and drop the `textview`, the Bar Button Item just wont highlight.

What am I missing?

PS: it works with UITextfield only.. why ?? `o.O'`

Comment: Why do you want to use a `UITextView` as a subview of a bar button? text view are supposed to hold bigger space than in a tool bar

Comment: What I really needed is a mutline-textfield, one that can expand like the iMessage one, my research shows I need to use a Textview instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the `inputAccessoryView`, it's a `UIView` which gets displayed when the textview becomes first responder. hence when the keyboard shows.

You can customize the `UIView` to hold all controls you want: textview, buttons, etc. More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html#jumpTo_10).

Basically, you implement your custom keyboard tool bar which is a UIView subclass (I assume you want something like the messages app), then you set the custom UIView to the `inputAccessoryView` property of the UITextView. here is a relevant link to get you started: http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html

Comment: I didn't get it. I need to add a UIView inside of the toolbar?

Comment: the link is invalid